# WPF Binding to property and setting another

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm using MVVM in my WPF application.
I have a Window that has a view inside it. In that view a value can be changed and I will bind it to a TextBox in my main Window:

```
<TextBox
    Text="{Binding Path=myViewModel.MyValue">
</TextBox>
```

Now I would need to bind this **myViewModel.MyValue** to a property inside my main window view model, so that I can use it to perform a filter in a collection.

Can I use a Setter or any other thing that sets the value of my **MainViewModel.Property** whenever the **myViewModel.MyValue** changes?
If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your "sub" view's view model live inside your "main" window's viewmodel?  If so, you can simply trigger these things through the setters.

If not, you might be able to use an ancestor binding and drive this from the UI.  It's not ideal (I'd assume you are trying to avoid the parent and child views from having specific knowledge of each other), but it would work.

Here's a RelativeSource sample that is pretty simple.  These can get quite complex.  Use with caution:
http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2006/04/101102.html

If you *do* decide to go the RelativeSource route, you ought to know how to debug bindings.  Use [this link](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=52) for that.  She gives several techniques for this, but if you are using .NET 3.5, I'd recommend using that method (near the end of the article).

Answer (score 0):

Use binding again, this time from code. Take a look at the FrameworkElement.SetBinding member function.

Comment: This is not something you'd do in an MVVM application.  A ViewModel wouldn't have knowledge of the View and vice-versa.